# I want to get a firebase data directly from database by specific 'bucket/key'

Tags: firebase

How could I get a specific datavalue from firebase realtime database by specific 'key'. Don't want any list type data; just a single value.

Comment: Have you seen [Retrieving Data Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js)?

Comment: Which Firebase product and what platform are you coding in? Can you show us what you've attempted and what your firebase structure looks like? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `firebase.database().ref()` to get the reference of the document you are looking for and then get the value, for example to get a User with a specific id:

```js
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().username) || 'Anonymous';
  // ...
});
```

[Check out the Firebase Realtime Database documentation for further details.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)